# HTTPS To http redirect issue. How to overcome?

Tags: apache, wordpress, redirects, http

Have already seen suggests on how to rewrite https to http. currently using this technique :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http ://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Problem : I am currently on Hostgator VPS and have found Google indexing my HTTPS pages. Weird for me as never bought an SSL. My site is a blog only. When spoke to Google forums, ( https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/2Hz46t44nwk/7voZWudFtAQJ ), they say I should redirect https to http. Now when I have redirected this using the above method, I am still getting SSL warning in browsers. And found that Google is still indexing my new pages with https.

I feel as I do not have an SSL, adding a redirect in https doesn't work. So if Google indexes my https page, then I should go and buy SSL, and tell there to redirect https to http. Why would I do that? Please help me, reduced the traffic by nearly 30% because of this.

**Have even told search engines to go to this file (disallows everything) if they are on https**.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_ssl.txt
```

Comment: You will see such warning in browser when domain name in SSL certificate does not match requested domain name. Because SSL (`S` part of HTTPS) executes before http connection is made (before mod_rewrite has a change to kick in), you will see it (warning) unless you install correct certificate. You better find out why you are indexed via HTTPS (cannot help here, unfortunately)

Comment: thanks. have consulted hostgator people and they say plesk automatically adds an ssl. any further solution?

Comment: Except disabling SSL (removing such binding) in Plesk -- nope, sorry. Maybe somebody else has better ideas -- I have never met such issue myself and don't really know where to start (except all what I have said already).

Answer (score 2):

Disable or remove SSL from Plesk ( http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/ssl-setup-use/how-to-setup-and-use-a-shared-ssl-windows ), submit a clean sitemap to Google Webmaster Center. I would avoid creating redirects if you can solve this by disabling SSL and letting Google re-index your site properly.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following meta tag in your HTTPS pages

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```